# Is there a way to limit time and memory resources for running a bash command?

Tags: bash

Basically I want to run my compiled C++ code and limit execution time (to a second for example) and memory (to 100k) like the online judges. Is it possible by adding options to the command? This has to be done without modifying the source code of course.

Comment: Read about `cgroups` which is probably alternative way to limit process' resources. See [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/cgroups) and [RedHat documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Resource_Management_Guide/Starting_a_Process.html). In particular [`cgexec`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/cgexec.1.html) command can be helpful.

Answer (score 6):

Try `ulimit` command, it can set limits on CPU time and memory.

Try this example

```
bash -c 'ulimit -St 1 ; while true; do true; done;'
```

The result you will get will be

```
CPU time limit exceeded (core dumped)
```

Comment: Hey thanks i think this solves it. You can add a -v option with the number of max kilobytes (for virtual memory).

Answer (score 2):

To limit time you can use "timeout" command

```
timeout 15s command
```

Check this for more details: [link](http://coldattic.info/shvedsky/pro/blogs/a-foo-walks-into-a-bar/posts/40)